# Algorithm to find the relation between elements in a dataset

Tags: algorithm, set, relation

I have a dataset consisting of relations from a set to another. Simplified example as follows:

{A, B, C} -> {1, 2, 3} # order may change {2, 1, 3} is also possible

{B, D} -> {2, 4}

{A, D} -> {1, 4}

---

I need to find the relation between elements such that:

A -> 1

B -> 2

C -> 3

D -> 4

Is there any known algorithm for this type of tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this with maximum matching in bipartite graphs. Make two sets of vertices e.g. one contains vertices: S_1 = {A,B,C,D} and the other contains elements S_2 = {1,2,3,4}.

Add edge between S_1[i] and S_2[j] if there are sets s'_1,s'_2 such that S_1[i] ∈ s'_1, S_2[j]∈ s'_2 and s'_1 → s'_2. And then find the maximum matching in the corresponding bipartite graph with one of well known algorithms (e.g. hungarian algorithm).

For example in your case we have edges:

```
A,1
A,2
A,3
A,4
B,1
B,2
B,3
B,4
C,1
C,2
C,3
D,2
D,4
```

And e.g. the solution you suggested is just a maximum matching in that graph.